# How do i extract a sub string which is composed of certain characters from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

For example,
suppose I have a string "beabeefeab".
I want to extract a substring which is composed of only 'b' and 'a' 
that is "babab".

I applied brute force by implementing a nested loop and deleting all characters but 'b' and 'a'

Comment: You have described your problem but have not demonstrated any attempt to solve it.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I applied brute force by implementing a nested loop by deleting all characters but 'b' and 'a'

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a simple list comprehension

```
a = "beabeefeab"
print("".join([i for i in a if (i == 'a' or i =='b')]))
```

**Output:**

```
babab
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but it works.

```
a = "beabeefeab"
answer = ""
for char in a:
    if char == "a" or char == "b":
        answer += char

print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
babab
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `set` to keep the allowed chars, making this a bit more extensible:

```
s = "beabeefeab"
allowed = set('ab')
print("".join(x for x in s if x in allowed))
```

Comment: Can you please trace or explain how this one is working.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Same as the one by Rakesh, except that I am not explicitly filtering against the individual characters, but against membership in a `set`.